# Default pagination fails in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating an basic pagination with Laravel5.1 , I receive the following PHP code.

```
public function postFindUsers(){
    $name= \Request::input('name');
    $findUserByNombre = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->paginate(6);
    return view('users.findUsers')->with('users',$findUserByNombre);
}
```

This code returns the list of users correctly but in the view I don't know how to solve this error , I have the following code.

```
<div class="hotel-list listing-style3 hotel">
    @foreach($users as $usuario)
   <article class="box">
        <figure class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
            <a href="{{ URL::asset('detalle') }}" class="hover-effect"><img width="270" height="160" alt="" src="{{$usuario->foto}}"></a>
        </figure>
        <div class="details col-sm-7 col-md-8">
            <a href="{{ URL::asset('detalle') }}">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h4 class="box-title">{{$usuario->nombre}} {{$usuario->primer_apellido}} {{$usuario->segundo_apellido}}<small><i class="soap-icon-departure yellow-color"></i> {{$usuario->fecha_nacimiento}}</small></h4>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{{$usuario->descripcion}}</p>
                <div>
                    <a class="button btn-small full-width text-center" title="" href="detalle">CONSULTAR</a>
                </div>
            </div>
                                                </a>

        </div>
    </article>
    @endforeach                              
    {{$users->render()}}
</div>
```

However , when I put this url in the page `public/search?page=2` , this url return a typical error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

Could anyone help to me ?

/**UPDATE**/

```
Route::get('/search-users', 'UserController@getUsers');  
Route::post('/search', 'UserController@postFindUsers');
```

Comment: Almost sure `public/busqueda` route is set to accepts only *POST* requests, so you should change the route to something like this: `Route::match(['POST', 'GET'] ...)`

Comment: Or atleast show the routes, its clearly in there the error is :)

Comment: Yes , but I don't have any problems with others versions of Larave.

Comment: Why are you calling `public/busqueda?page=2` should it not be `public/search?page=2?`

Comment: Sorry , I forget to change the name.

Comment: use a get request , its better in this case i think

Comment: I change to GET it's more easy , thanks everyone !

Comment: lol already righting an answer about that should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Get request

**routes**

```
Route::get('/search', 'UserController@getFindUsers');
```

**controller**

```
public function getFindUsers(){
   $name= \Request::input('name');
    $findUserByNombre = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->paginate(6);
    return view('users.findUsers')->with('users',$findUserByNombre);
}
```

**HTML**

```
 {!! Form::input ('search' , 's' , null , ['class' => 'form-control'] , ['placeholder' => 'Search...'])  !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return both `$findUserByNombre` and `$links` in the function `postFindUsers()`

```
public function postFindUsers(){
    $name= \Request::input('name');
    $findUserByNombre = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->paginate(6);
    $links = $findUserByNombre->render();
    return view('users.findUsers', compact('findUserByNombre', 'links'));
}
```

And in the view **findUsers.blade.php**, just add

`<div>{!! $links !!}</div>`

And change the request method from `post` to `get`.

```
Route::get('/search', 'UserController@postFindUsers');
```

To get the 2nd page, just call the following url

```
public/search?page=2
```